# Is the wifi hotspot feature available on newer android phones?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, wifi-hotspot

I have a captivate glide running android 4.0.4 with at&t and it has a wifi hotspot feature that I can turn on to share my data connection via wifi.
I'm planning on getting a samsung galaxy s6 or s7 and was wondering if this feature is still available. I try to read all the documentation but it's all marketing hype and doesn't mention things like this that I can find.
Anybody use this feature? Is it still a thing? Are there any phones that support it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all phones support this fundamental feature nowadays, so much that it's no longer on marketing materials. I use the feature exclusively on some of my phones - I have data SIMs in them and carry them around to provide connection for my main phone. S7 even supports relaying WiFi connections which is rare.

However, do note that some carriers (e.g. Verizon) would sometimes lock the feature behind certain restrictions, like you need to have the carrier's SIM, or you need to have a payment plan with tethering enabled.

Comment: awesome thanks. I had no idea. I appreciate the info.